# Modelagem de BD para "marketing multinivel"

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, administração-postgresql

Fala pessoal,

Estou trabalhando num app que consiste em indicação de pessoas, igual aos chamados marketing multinível.

A ideia geral consistem em:

*Pessoa A indica a pessoa B (NÍVEL 1), se a pessoa B indicar a pessoa C (N1 da pessoa B e N2 da pessoa A) e assim até o N5.*

Como posso planejar esse tipo de tabela?

OBS: Vai precisar ser em um SGBD postgresql, pois será uma adição a um sistema já existente

Estou aberto a qualquer sugestão

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma tabela que possua uma FK para ela mesma. Assim você usa recursão para descrever a estrutura hierárquica de indicações. Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoas (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  indicador integer REFERENCES pessoas(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  -- Demais campos
);
```